# Get records by hash value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to get records from table by hash value.
Here is record example:

```
Activity:0x0000000709be18> {
                :id => 1,
      :trackable_id => 3,
    :trackable_type => "User",
          :owner_id => 1,
        :owner_type => "User",
               :key => "user.ban",
        :parameters => {
        :status => "new"
    },
      :recipient_id => nil,
    :recipient_type => nil,
        :created_at => Wed, 01 Jun 2016 22:19:39 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Wed, 01 Jun 2016 22:19:39 UTC +00:00
}
```

I need to get all Activities with paremeters status new (parameters[:status] == 'new').

This code works, but I need to return activerecord relation not an array.

```
Activity.select{|act| act.parameters == { status: 'new'}}
```

Comment: `Activity.where('status = ?', 'new')`

Comment: parameters is a hash, and status is key of this hash

Comment: What version of Postgresql are you using? What is the type of the `parameters` column?

Comment: Is the `parameters` column `json` or `jsonb`? `hstore`? `text` containing serialized YAML?

Comment: @muistooshort, from this snippet it looks like just ActiveRecord object

Comment: @JoeHalfFace: But `:parameters => { :status => "new" }` is inside the ActiveRecord object so the question is what it looks like inside the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to search within a serialized field, but you can use `LIKE` with some limitations.

`Activity.where('parameters LIKE ?', '%status: new%')`

This is working, but I do suggest adding a custom field, just like what public activity gem owner has mentioned:

> "Besides the few fields that every activity has, you can also set
>   custom fields. This could be very beneficial, as parameters are a
>   serialized hash, which cannot be queried easily from the database."

Comment: But you're assuming that the model is using `serialize` to stuff some YAML into a `text` column. PostgreSQL supports JSON and hstore columns that can store data like that and query it without all the YAML noise.

Comment: Oh my bad for making assumptions. But according to the model structure I am pretty sure he is using a gem call public activity, which `parameters` has a `text` column.